# Attribute specialization & constraint module

Tags: dita

I have the requirement from user to make the specialization attribute @a,@b,@c based on @base attribute. And @a and @b are applicable for all of the elements but for about @c it is desired to use it only for `<fig>` elements. `<fig>` element exists in OASIS scheme (DTD) and is not my specialization element.

As far as I know the attribute specialization can be done by the following RELAX NG coding.

```
   <define name="aAtt-d-attribute">
     <optional>
         <attribute name="a">
             <a:documentation>Specifies @a to which an element applies.
             </a:documentation>
         </attribute>
     </optional>    
   </define>
   <define name="base-attribute-extensions" combine="interleave">
       <ref name="aAtt-d-attribute"/>
   </define>
```

But I am not sure how to write the constraint module for @c in RELAX NG and integrate them into shell .rng file. Please give me your advice.

Comment: The most important point is to add new attributes to existing (OASIS TC supplied) elements via minimum conforming way. The original discussion can be found in [https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/dita-users/conversations/topics/39272](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/dita-users/conversations/topics/39272)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you need to process `@c`, I think. If it does not have to be processed like `@base`, you can probably just add it via a specialized `<fig>` element.

**EDIT:**
As @JulioV said, specializations based on `@base` or `@props` are global. I'd recommend to use a Schematron validation to force authors to not use the attributes on specific elements. This also works very well with Oxygen XML.

This is a small Schematron example that forbids using the `@id` attribute on `<fig>` elements and offers a Schematron Quick Fix to remove the attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" 
            queryBinding="xslt2"
            xmlns:sqf="http://www.schematron-quickfix.com/validator/process">
     <sch:pattern>
     <sch:rule context="*[contains(@class, ' topic/fig ')]">
         <sch:assert test="not(@id)" sqf:fix="removeId">
             Figure elements must not have an ID.
         </sch:assert>
         <sqf:fix id="removeId">
             <sqf:description>
                 <sqf:title>Remove ID</sqf:title>
             </sqf:description>
         <sqf:delete match="@id"/>
     </sqf:fix>
 </sch:rule>
```

Comment: Specializing `<fig>` does not match my intention. The reference discussion is here: [https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/dita-users/conversations/topics/39272](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/dita-users/conversations/topics/39272)

Comment: Thank you for giving Schematron example. But is has no meaning for my question.

Answer (score 1):

DITA architecture is such that any attribute specialization, whether done on @base or @props are global. The only way to constrain a variable to a specific element is to go through all the modules and make sure to include the domain that contains the attribute only on the element requires that attribute. It might be easier to configure your XML editor to only surface the attribute on the elements you need the attribute on.

Comment: What context are you using the word `variable`?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to create a constraint that is not 100% strictly conforming but that is much more convenient.

Namely, you have a normal attribute domain module that declares the attribute just as you would for a global @props or @base specialization.

But rather than integrating it normally (which would make it global), you don't don't integrate it.

Instead, you create a separate constraint module that simply adds the attribute to the element types you want it to appear on.

This gives you the same effect as if you had redeclared every attribute list except those for the elements where you want it to appear but is obviously practical, rather than impractical.

This is still a constraint in that it is constraining what would otherwise be a global attribute to be a limited-use attribute.

If there is a need to make the declarations 100% strictly conforming then you simply remove the constraint and integrate the attribute normally, making it global. No existing document will break as a result.

Comment: Thank you ! I will try this method.